# ItemsSource rendering delay

Tags: wpf, performance, binding, datagrid, rendering

When I set the .ItemSource() on a Datagrid, the call almost returns instantly, but there is a large delay before the actual rows are rendered. This is very noticable, and I wonder why this happens because all other rendering actions happens instantly. For example, scrolling is super-fast and removing/re-ordering columns renders instantly. So this delay only happens when setting a new .ItemsSource. The datagrid has no custom styles/triggers/templates, so I cannot understand why rendering takes so long. If I resize the window to a very small size, the delay is gone, so it's not the binding itself that is slow.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem ?

Comment: @RobotMess Yes, to some degree, but I cant remember how. I believe it had something to do with using .DataSource() instead of .ItemSource() but im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on several reasons: How fast is your DataSource, how many rows are in it and the most important one: do you use grouping in your DataGrid? If so, there is a known bug in the DataGrid control, making it significant slow when it has to deal with large data and grouping.

Comment: I do not use grouping, and I put debug statement in the properties of the objects I bind to, and they are printed immediately after setting the ItemsSource, the rendering isnt finished untill much later, so that seems to confirm it's not the binding that is slow.

Comment: Is the rendering complex (Large Datatemplates, long animations, big pictures, color gradients, a.s.o.)

Comment: No, it's just the plain standard datagrid, without any customization.

Comment: The best way to help you is, when you provide some sample code.